# クラステンプレートの部分特殊化のマッチングの仕組みについて

Tags: c++

部分特殊化のマッチングはどのように行われているのでしょうか？
例えば次のコードが何故コンパイルできないのかわかりません。

```
$ clang -v
clang version 9.0.0-2~ubuntu18.04.2 (tags/RELEASE_900/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

```cpp
template <bool, typename T>
struct hoge {};

template <bool, typename T>
struct hoge<true, T>
{};

int main()
{
    hoge<true, int> h;
    (void)h;
}
```

```
error: class template partial specialization contains a template parameter that cannot be deduced;
    this partial specialization will never be used
```

マッチすることがないという旨のエラーのようです。
↓のようにすればコンパイルはできるのですが、↑のコードでも上手くいきそうな気がしてしまいます。

```cpp
template <bool, typename T>
struct hoge {};

template <typename T>
struct hoge<true, T>
{};

int main()
{
    hoge<true, int> h;
    (void)h;
}
```

C++11のドラフトには次のようにありましたが、関数テンプレートの実引数推定と同様の方法で決定されるのでしょうか？
https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf

> 14.5.5.1 Matching of class template partial specializations
> When a class template is used in a context that requires an instantiation of the class, it is necessary to determine whether the instantiation is to be generated using the primary template or one of the partial specializations. **This is done by matching the template arguments of the class template specialization with the template argument lists of the partial specializations.**
>
> — If exactly one matching specialization is found, the instantiation is generated from that specialization.
> — If more than one matching specialization is found, the partial order rules (14.5.5.2) are used to determine whether one of the specializations is more specialized than the others. If none of the specializations is more specialized than all of the other matching specializations, then the use of the class template is ambiguous and the program is ill-formed.
> — If no matches are found, the instantiation is generated from the primary template.
>
> **A partial specialization matches a given actual template argument list if the template arguments of the partial specialization can be deduced from the actual template argument list (14.8.2).**

その場合、どうやってクラステンプレートを関数テンプレートと同様に評価するのか、上記コードの例の`部分特殊化のテンプレート実引数true`はどのような扱いになるのかなど、具体的な定義はどこかに書いてあるのでしょうか？

> 14.5.5.2 Partial ordering of class template specializations

のexampleでは、

```cpp
template<int I, int J> void f(X<I, J, int>); // A
template<int I> void f(X<I, I, int>); // B
```

のように、クラスを引数に取る関数を仮定していましたが、これは順位付けをするための方法として記載されているようで、マッチングにもこれが適用されるのか判断がつきませんでした。

また、仮にこの方法で評価する場合でも、次のコードはコンパイルできてしまいました。（このコードが仕様の解釈として正しいか分かりませんが）

```cpp
template <bool, typename T>
class X {};

template <bool, typename T>
void f(X<true, T>) {};

int main()
{
    X<true, int> x;
    f<true, int>(x);
}
```

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.class.spec.match#1

> This is done by matching the template arguments of the class template specialization with the template argument lists of the partial specializations.

> (クラステンプレートの特殊化のテンプレート引数を部分特殊化のテンプレート引数リストと照合することによって行われます。)

https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.class.spec.match#4

> In a type name that refers to a class template specialization, (e.g., A<int, int, 1>) the argument list shall match the template parameter list of the primary template. The template arguments of a specialization are deduced from the arguments of the primary template.

> (クラステンプレートの特殊化を参照する型名 (たとえば、 `A<int, int, 1>` ) では引数リストはプライマリテンプレートのテンプレートパラメーターリストと一致する必要があります。 特殊化のテンプレート引数はプライマリテンプレートの引数から推定されます。)

つまり質問の例で言えば `hoge<true, int> h;` の宣言のときにはまずプライマリテンプレートが受け取ってから、 `<true, int>` にあてはまる部分特殊化である `hoge<true, T>` が発見されて、この部分特殊化のテンプレート引数 `<bool, typename T>` の実際の内容を推定しようとします。

部分特殊化のテンプレート引数は `hoge<true, T>` のほうを元にして推論が試みられるので `hoge<true, T>` で使っていないテンプレート引数は推論のしようがないです。

Comment: 理解しました！ありがとうございます。
```
template <bool, bool, typename T>
struct hoge {};

template <bool b, typename T>
struct hoge<true, b, T>
{};

int main()
{
 hoge<true, true, int> h;
 (void)h;
}
```
ならできるということですね。テンプレートむずかしー！